# DotNet Core: How to cross-platform Client Certificate TLS Authentication?

Tags: .net-core, smartcard, pkcs#11, hsm, pkcs11interop

I'm trying to develop a cross-platform app (windows/mac os x) that needs to sign XML files and make web requests on a server using ClientCertificate authentication...

The main constraint is that I need to use a certificate on a smartcard...

I'm using dotnet core 2.1 for the moment.

First I did try to use dotnet core X509Store, but on MacOs I couln't access the PrivateKey object in any case (mandatory for XML signing.), then I discarded this lead.

Then I used pkcs11interop with the vendor-specific dlls to access the smartcard, and it worked well for XML signing (I wrapped pkcs11interop calls inside a RSA object, then I used this object as SigningKey inside SignedXml,) but it did not work for ClientCertificate connection.

Normally I use this method to connect to the server (dotnet framework 4.6.1, windows only) :

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://sometlsserver.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And the certificate is generated:

```
var certAttr = session.GetAttributeValue(handle, new List<CKA>
{
    CKA.CKA_VALUE,
};
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certAttr[0].GetValueAsByteArray());
```

When I try to connect with my classic method, I have several exceptions :

```
System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Le message reçu était inattendu ou formaté de façon incorrecte
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
...
```

I think that the cryptographic operation made by the private key needed during the TLS handshake is missing and it simply fails...

I did try to add my RSA object used for XML signing in the private key property but with dotnet core it ends with a PlatformNotSupportedException...

```
cert.PrivateKey = myRSAObject; // simple
```

I'm wondering if that's possible to do that without using a third party library...

Note: Translation of the french error message "Message was unexpected or incorrectly formatted."

Thanks.

(edit: better formatting)

Comment: The `PrivateKey` property setter was replaced with `CopyWithPrivateKey` extension methods that support RSA, DSA and ECC (eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.copywithprivatekey?view=netframework-4.8). All of these work on .NET Core on all platforms.

Comment: @FilipNavara thx for pointing that method out! That might be a gamechanger if `RSA` will be used by SSL implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that method, I'll try that asap.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. CopyWithPrivateKey is expecting an exponent and a modulus for the private key, and the private exponent can't be extracted from the smartcard...
I'm currently investigating bouncycastle, seems promising ?

Answer (score 1):

`X509Certificate2` is legacy class designed only for Windows that currently has no widely usable alternative or sane multiplatform replacement.

When you construct `X509Certificate2` object using `byte[]` value of `CKA_VALUE` attribute you get just the certificate without the private key.

The closest you can get to ".NET compatible implementation" is to implement class derived from `RSA` as I did in [Pkcs11Interop.X509Store](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/blob/0.2.0/src/Pkcs11Interop.X509Store/Pkcs11RsaProvider.cs) project. It will work with `SignedXML` class but as you already found out it won't be usable with most SSL classes that require `X509Certificate2` object with correctly associated `PrivateKey` property.

IMO you have three options:

1. Switch to appropriate .NET Core version and create `X509Certificate2` object associated with your `RSA` implementation using [`CopyWithPrivateKey` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.copywithprivatekey?view=netframework-4.8) as pointed out by @FilipNavara in his comment. Such `X509Certificate2` object might (or rather might not) work with SSL implementation.
2. Use PFX/PKCS#12 file that contains SSL client certificate with private key protected by user password. Such file can be loaded in `X509Certificate2` object correctly associated `PrivateKey` property on most platforms supported by .NET Core.
3. Find or write SSL client implementation that will not require `X509Certificate2` object with associated `PrivateKey` property. I'm currently not aware of any library with such design.